# The code does not assign value to an inherited function parameter and do not call function

Tags: c++

The code does not reduce the default health value, just prints default value out. It does not call GetName() and GetHealth() functions that are inside the TakeDamage() function. The code can run without problem. Screen out put is below the code. Where is the problem here? How do I fix?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Creature
{
public:
    Creature();
    void setName(string name);
    void TakeDamage(float Damage);
    string GetName();
    float GetHealth();
private:
    string Name;
    float Health;
};

class Voldemort : public Creature
{
private:
    void AvadaKedavra();
public:
    void MakeMagic();

};

void Creature::setName(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    cout << name << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Voldemort Anger;
    Anger.MakeMagic();
    Anger.setName("Harry Potter");
    return 0;
}

Creature::Creature()
{
    cout << "A creature has been created" << endl;
    Health=100;
}

string Creature::GetName()
{
    return Name;
}

float Creature::GetHealth()
{
    return Health;
}

void Creature::TakeDamage(float Damage)
{
    float Total;
    Total = Health - Damage;

    if (Total <= 0.f)
    {
        cout << GetName() << " has died" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Health -= Damage;
    }

    cout << "Health: " << Health << endl;
    cout << "Health: " << GetHealth() << endl;
}

void Voldemort::MakeMagic()
{
    AvadaKedavra();
}

void Voldemort::AvadaKedavra()
{
    TakeDamage(100);
}
```

Screen:
A creature has been created
has died
Health: 100
Health: 100
Harry Potter

Comment: You have at least two problems. 1) In TakeDamage if creature dies you don't adjust its Health. In the line before you print has died, set the Health value to 0 (or whatever value you use to mark it as dead. 2) You call setName after you you call MakeMagic, so at the time the creature dies it doesn't yet have a name.

Comment: Thanks but I have to figure out how to reduce the health value, and the reason why the code does not recognise GetName() and GetHealth() functions

Comment: @CraigR reversing Anger.MakeMagic(); and
    Anger.setName("Harry Potter"); worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Total <= 0.f)
{
    cout << GetName() << " has died" << endl;
}
else
{
    Health -= Damage;
}
```

You don't change the health when `Total`  is less or equal  0, which is the case when you call `TakeDamage(100)`